# Apex test class for trigger - beginners guide

Tags: class, testing, triggers, code-coverage, apex

I am relatively inexperienced with coding and have never been been forced to write test classes before. I do not understand it conceptually. I have written the following trigger:

```
trigger CreateNewInvoiceAndUpdateCM on CampaignMember(after insert, after update){
for (CampaignMember cm: trigger.new){

    if(cm.Status == 'Needs Renewal and Invoice'){
        Asset memb = [SELECT Id, Product2Id FROM Asset WHERE Id = :cm.Membership__c];
        Product2 prod = [SELECT Id, ProductCode FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :memb.Product2Id];
        Pricebook2 pb =[SELECT Id, Name FROM Pricebook2 WHERE Name = 'Standard Price Book'];
        PricebookEntry pbe = [SELECT Id, UnitPrice, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id = :pb.Id AND Product2Id = :prod.Id];

        Invoice__c inv = new Invoice__c();
        inv.Membership__c = cm.Membership__c;
        inv.Contact__c = cm.ContactId;
        inv.Price__c = pbe.UnitPrice;
        insert inv;



        CampaignMember newCm = [select Id, Invoice__c FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id = :cm.Id];
        newCm.Invoice__c = inv.Id;
        newCM.Status = 'Needs Renewal';
        update newCm;

        }}
        }
```

But then I have no idea how to properly write a test class. I have gone through all the documentation on the Salesforce site and countless posts on here but I have failed to get my code coverage up from 13% (2/15)[What does this mean btw?].

The test class I have written is basically just an attempt to get everything in there in the hope that the code coverage will go up. I have no idea what I'm actually supposed to be doing with the test class:

```
@isTest 

private class testCreateNewInvoiceAndUpdateCM{

static testMethod void testCreateNewInvoiceAndUpdateCM(){

PricebookEntry pbe = new PriceBookEntry();
pbe.UnitPrice = 2;

Campaign camp = new Campaign();
camp.Name = 'Test Campaign';
insert camp;

Account acc = new Account();
acc.Name ='Test Account';
insert acc;

Contact cont= new Contact();
cont.LastName = 'LastName';
cont.AccountId = acc.Id;
insert cont;


Asset ass = new Asset();
ass.Name = 'Test Asset';
ass.Membership_Start_Date__c = System.today();
ass.ContactId = cont.Id;
ass.AccountId = ass.Id;
insert ass;

Invoice__c inv = new Invoice__c();
inv.Membership__c = ass.Id;
inv.Contact__c = cont.Id;
inv.Price__c = pbe.UnitPrice;
insert inv;

CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(); 
cm.CampaignId = camp.Id;
cm.ContactId = cont.Id;
cm.Membership__c = ass.Id;
cm.Status = 'Needs Renewal and Invoice';
cm.Invoice__c = Inv.Id;

insert cm;


CampaignMember cm2 = [select Id, Status, Invoice__c  from CampaignMember where Id = :cm.Id];
System.assertEquals('Needs Renewal and Invoice',cm.Status);







   }
}
```

Can anyone help me please it's driving me insane?

Answer (score 1):

Before you write your test class, you need to rewrite the trigger.  You NEVER query inside of a for loop.  You should also minimize the number of queries by using joins.  You should review the apex best practices guide.  Start here:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

Answer (score 0):

(2/15) means that 2 out of 15 lines (of your trigger) passed the test, you've got 13 more lines to test, which means your test class code did not cover those 13 lines.
could you please specify which 2 lines of your trigger passed the test ? that will definitely help understand where your problem is better.